# How to share internet between a Ubuntu and XP?

Tags: networking, lubuntu

I am having an Internet connection which i have to share via LAN to my friends. I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 but the problem is that i can't share the connection.

As I used to do I gave eth0 (the interface connected to my friends) the name share and in the network settings, gave the option share with other computers. But the problem is that when I save it, the "share" is not connecting but the name of my eth0 lan card is showing constantly as connected and not connected.

When I configured "share" with other options in the drop down (Manual, Link local only etc.) there was no problem. guys please help me..... we have got no other options for sharing the internet connection.....

Comment: How is your computer connected to internet?. Please give us more information about the desired setup.

Answer (score 1):

It is well described in [ConnectionSharing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) ubuntu help page.